# Output the price of the fertilizer per pound and the cost of fertilizing per square

Tags: java

During each summer John and Jessica grow vegetables in their back yard and buy seeds and fertilizer from a local nursery. The nursery carries different types of vegetable fertilizers in various bag sizes. When buying a particular fertilizer, they want to know the price of the fertilizer per pound and the cost of fertilizing per square foot. The following program prompts the user to enter the size of the fertilizer bag - in pounds, the cost of the bag, and the area - in square feet that can be covered by the bag. The program should output the desired result

This is what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Ch3_PrExercise4
{

static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    double cost;
    double area;
    double bagSize;

    System.out.print("Enter the amount of fertilizer in pounds, in one bag: ");
    bagSize = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter the cost of the, " + bagSize + " pound fertilizer bag: ");
    cost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter the area, in square feet, that can be fertilized by one bag: ");
    area = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.printf("The cost of the fertilizer per pound is: $%.2f%n", bagSize/cost);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The cost of fertilizing per square foot is: $%.4f%n", area/cost);


}
}
```

PS: I'm new to Java. I'm trying to figure it out. Any response will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the last few lines should use `cost/bagSize` (since you want dollars per pound, so you should have dollars on top and pounds on the bottom) and `cost/area` (since you want dollars per area, so you should have dollars on top and area on the bottom):

```
    System.out.printf("The cost of the fertilizer per pound is: $%.2f%n", cost/bagSize);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The cost of fertilizing per square foot is: $%.4f%n", cost/area);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea to improve this program? or any workaround in this? Thanks for response anyway @Chai T. Rex

Comment: I would remove some of the `System.out.println();` statements so that the user sees output text that looks better organized and nicer, but other than that, it seems to work nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much @Chai T. Rex. You are very helpful. Sorry for intruding you, sad to say im noob in this language it will take time practice to master it.